# iOS App crash with SIGTRAP in iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, symbolicatecrash

I have an app which is written in swift and uses AFNetwork and some other helpers written in Obj c. On my clients device (iPhone 6+) he is getting an SIGTRAP error, I have tried to recreate the issue on the testing devices that we have and on all the simulators but could not recreate it.

Below is the stack trace, it crashed twice:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12077304/
When I symbolicate the crash report it is pointing to:

```
-[Instagram getOwnBaseUrl] (in DiaryApp) (Instagram.m:118)
```

And on the second instance it point to:

```
[UIAlertView(AFNetworking) showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:]_block_invoke (in DiaryApp) (UIAlertView+AFNetworking.m:72)
```

Crash Log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12077328/

I am not able to pin point the exact cause for the crash. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

**SIGTRAP** is not the error it is the exception. It doesn't show the origin of the crash. This exceptions throw into Main thread on Main/Next Runloop, so the stacktrace of the main thread does not show the origin of it.

It happen like NSArray `indexOutOfBounds` or library or anything else

reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597953/how-to-debug-exc-crash-sigtrap)

**signal Types**

[image]

Comment: try once in release mode,

Comment: My app is live at app store, And I am getting Sigtrap issue notification, but app not getting crash. How to stop this sigtrap?